# firewall breaks my splash page

Tags: networking

when connecting to my Pi hotspot, everything works great. however, i'd like to lock it down. i found and use the following configuration. when i do this, the configuration seems to work perfectly. however, when connecting to the network my splash page no longer opens up automatically. as it sits, i can either have a working firewall or have a splash page that automatically opens up. but, not both.

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [23:2584]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1161:105847]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

any help getting my Pi firewall running and allowing the spash page to continue to start upon connection would be most appreciated. thanks.

Comment: what is `splash page`? .... how is it being "opened"?

Comment: it's just a simple .html file. devices like iphone and my laptop just auto-magically open the page when connectedto a hotspot. as devices send their http request out to determine if there is internet access, my http server is setup to auto-forward all requests to my simple .html page. so, devices that allow that will open the page. however, for some reason when i enable the firewall via the settings above, it all stops working and i just have no idea why/how one would effect the other.

Comment: `it all stops working` ... what does it do? .... any errors?

Comment: when the firewall is off and someone connects to my network, the splash page shows up and all is fine. when i turn the firewall on, the splash page does not show up. also, i see no errors in the logs.

Comment: is the splash page being served on a different IP address?

Comment: all from the same Pi. it's really odd. i am not sure why this "feature" for devices to pull up a browser on connection would stop with the firewall. all i can assume is "something" is happening behind the scenes on a port that was closed. i am thinking i will try different iptable configuration by adding pieces back slowly until it breaks. if it's a specific port, gonna take me a minute. but, gotta try.